# Oreo TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY, Not able to click on any part of display

Tags: android

After adding Application Overlay using WindowManager.LayoutParams in Oreo, I'm not able to click on any part display on phone, Touch event is not considered.
Here is my code

```
 int LAYOUT_FLAG;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
                } else {
                    LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY;
                }


                layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        1,
                        1,
                        LAYOUT_FLAG,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION

                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH

                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON
                        ,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT
                );
                layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add this additional flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE))

Comment: Thanks @shmakova even we have to add WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL

Comment: @RakshithKumar This flag will also enable FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL whether or not that is explicitly set

Comment: In my case i don't want any soft input methods and  key input focus, so that user can not send key or other button events to it. Those will instead go to whatever focusable window is behind it.

Comment: For some very odd reason `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` with `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` is still preventing touches to pass through to applications beneath it. Does this also work on 8.1?

Comment: I suppose, you should check width and height of your view @DanielF

Comment: @XarEAhmer be sure that size of your view not match_parent

Answer (score 0):

I have used it in my project and it's working on OREO

```
         if (mIconView == null) {
            mIconView = new IconView(getApplicationContext());
            iconViewLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            iconViewLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
            iconViewLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888; //Set window transparency
            iconViewLayoutParams.flags = FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE//window to accept click events
            iconViewLayoutParams.x = iconViewX;
            iconViewLayoutParams.y = iconViewY;
            iconViewLayoutParams.windowAnimations = R.style.IconViewAnimator;
            iconViewLayoutParams.width = Device.dip2px(getApplicationContext(),ICON_SIZE);
            iconViewLayoutParams.height = Device.dip2px(getApplicationContext(),ICON_SIZE);
            iconViewLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
            windowManager.addView(mIconView,iconViewLayoutParams);
        }
```