# Keyboard not working in TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY

Tags: android

I am using power button to perform a function, but in Android O **TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY** is providing the same function as **TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT** for which reason my keyboard and other back button is not working. I there any alternative to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250035/oreo-type-application-overlay-not-able-to-click-on-any-part-of-display